# Python: Index Out Of Range al recorrer un vector

Tags: python, array, lista

Trabajo en una función que debe buscar el elemento de mayor valor en un vector, pero me da error al compilar, el código es el siguiente:

```
def getVPPXSenialXMovXFilaMaximosMinimos(self, mov_canal, fila):
    line = [self.file.getVectorPorFilaPorSenial(mov_canal, fila)]
    i = 0
    while i < len(line):
        if line[i] >= line[i+1]:
            maxi = line[i]
        else:
            i += 1
    return maxi
```

El error siempre me da en la quinta línea.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El problema es el `line[i+1]` cuando i llega a ser el tamaño de la lista el +1 hace que se salga del rango de la lista, ten cuidado con lo que tienes en el else porque tú función puede caer en un bucle infinito, siempre hay que sumar a i uno independientemente que cumple o no la condición.

Te planteo dos posibles soluciones:

```
maxi = 0 
for d in line:
    if int(d) > maxi: 
        maxi = int(d)
 return maxi
```

La otra opción y más corta es

```
line = [ int(d) for d in line] 
maxi = max(line) 
return maxi
```

Estoy suponiendo que en línea tienes un string de números, si lo que tienes que comparar son caracteres te basta con quitar los int del código

Comment: Gracias por responer!
Me guié por tu sugerencia pero ahora me da el siguiente error:
TypeError: only size-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars
Cabe decir que cambié el int por un float ya que el arreglo contiene números decimales.

Comment: Cómo están separados los números? Si es posible pon un ejemplo de lo que contiene line

Comment: Lo logré Solucionar! El problema además de pasarme del índice tuvo que ver con la forma en la que declaré el vector, fuera de eso seguí tus pasos y va perfecto. Muchas Gracias.

Comment: Me alegro!!! :) No olvides poner tu pregunta cómo respondida. Saludos